# How to confirm Biometric's onAuthenticationSucceeded is legitimate

Tags: android, biometrics

I have a refresh token that is stored in my apps OAuth2 client. I cannot access the code that calls the code that uses the refresh token to get a new access token (and would prefer not to write custom code). Right now, I use a `BiometricPrompt` to confirm the user's identity. Since the refresh token is stored in the OAuth2 client, I do not need to use a cipher for encrypting/decrypting the refresh token. Instead, when `onAuthenticationSucceeded` returns in my biometric call, I simply tell the client to fetch me a new access token.

The issue here is a hacker can spoof the `onAuthenticationSucceeded` call with any result, and get the code to refresh the token since it's not using a cipher to decrypt anything.

So the final question is: Is there something I can do to confirm the legitimacy of the `onAuthenticationSucceeded` callback? I was thinking about adding a cipher to the authenticate call:

`biometricPrompt.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo, new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher));`

And then in the `onAuthenticationSucceeded` callback, I would confirm that the callback contained the original cipher that was sent with the call - but I don't really know how to compare these ciphers. Or perhaps there's another solution?

Comment: "The issue here is a hacker can spoof the onAuthenticationSucceeded call with any result" -- this would require root. An attacker with root has full control over the device and can register their own fingerprint, so they could just use your app normally and not have to do any spoofing. Are you sure that the spoofing scenario is an attack worth worrying about?

Comment: This issue was deemed by an outside party to be a security risk - however another risk on the list is that root detection is failing. Perhaps fixing that would fix this too. Thanks.